# Bootstrap stretched-link broken on Chrome and Edge, but works on Firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox

I'm having a strange issue at the moment. I have a table with several account listings, all of which have a clickable ID number. I've stretched the link across the entire row using `stretched-link`, and it works perfectly in Firefox. However, in a meeting with my team we discovered that the links are very broken in Chrome and Edge. For some reason, the bottom-most `stretched-link` is stretched across the entire page, instead of being confined to just the table row.

Here's a JSFiddle showcasing the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/v7ut1jL0/1/

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel not only the last, but all the links are taking full-body space.

It's an open issue in Bootstrap's repository https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/28608 .

As mentioned in this [comment](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/28608#issuecomment-479862777) It's probably due to the fact that

> "The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group,
>   table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group,
>   table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined."

See the [documentation reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position) here

Comment: Thank you. At this point I feel it might be simplest to revert to `display: table` instead of trying to use the `table` tags.